# Espresso - Why is Espresso finding this match ambiguous?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an `ExpandableListView` and I would like to `click()` one of its childs.

I have tried **LOADS OF** different ways but I just can't seem to understand how Espresso works.

For instance, why does this code do not work?

```
onData(withId(R.id.execexpList)).onChildView(is(withId(200))).perform(click())
```

For some divine reason, it returns "ambiguous match" to my ExpandableLIstView and other ListView of mine, but they have DIFFERENT ids.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Shouldn't `withId` take a `R.id`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have set each row in my `ExpandableListView` to a specific ID. So thats why I hardcoded it

Comment: You used `setId` on the view? First try `withId(is(int))`. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withId(int). If that does not work try `setTag`. Then use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withTagKey(int).

Comment: @JaredBurrows still ambiguous... How can I scroll down a `ExpandableListView`? It should be simple. I need to click a chilld of an `ExpandableListView` and thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onData()` is used to match an item inside the adapter of your ListView, not the actual view.

`onChildView()` is used to match a descendant of the ListView item that is matched in `onData()`.

If you have multiple AdapterViews in hierarchy you have to use `inAdapterView(Matcher<View>viewMatcher)` instead.

Official [API guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/DataInteraction.html) explains `onData()` usage in more details.